# MySQL "Access denied for user" after moving to new server

Tags: craft3, database, migration, mysql, aws

I've moved my Craft 3 installation to a new server.

When connecting to the original database, everything works fine.

However, when trying to connect to a new MySQL database (I've tried hosting this on both the new server and RDS) I'm getting the error: `Access denied for user`. I migrated to the new database by exporting via the Craft CP and then importing to the new database via MySQL Workbench.

I've tried connecting to both servers using a vanilla PHP connection (i.e. `new mysqli(host, username, password)` and it works perfectly fine -- I can even query the database and return results.

I only run into this error when the connection is opened by the original Craft `index.php` (the one with the `$app->run()` command). I've checked the output of the `(new Dotenv\Dotenv(CRAFT_BASE_PATH))->load();` line and it does properly return the settings defined in `.env`, which are the same as the ones used in the vanilla connection I mentioned above.

The side-effect of this error in `storage/logs/phperrors.log` is `Allowed memory size of <memory_limit> bytes exhausted ... in /var/www/craft/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Connection.php`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems this is not a Craft issue at all, but an issue with MySQL connections over PDO. Not sure of the precise environmental conditions that cause this, but I was experiencing the issue on both an AWS EC2 Ubuntu server as well as a MySQL RDS instance.

I discovered the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809418/unable-to-connect-to-aws-rds-through-pdo

In short, the `!` in my password was causing the problem. After replacing it with a `.`, the issue is resolved.

Thanks Amazon...